# When importing my class I lose access to functions from other modules

Tags: python, numpy, import, scope

I'm trying to learn how to do object oriented coding for scientific computing running a simulation; I'm using using numpy, etc. I've created my first class, `WC_unit`, which is located at `./classes/WC_class.py` (a subdirectory). I've created an `__init__.py` file (which is empty) in the `classes` directory.

The methods for the `WC_unit` class require some numpy functions, like exp

When I run the code (in ipython) from the terminal, using

```
%run WC_class.py
```

I can generate an instance of the class `E1 = WC_unit()` and I can run the associated methods on it, ie `E1.update()`
I can't really tell if it's working. I wrote some outer code in a script `test.py` located at . (above `./classes`) to test the objects I'm generating and I'm trying to import the class by using

```
from classes.WC_class import WC_unit
```

Now, when I create an instance `E1` of the class and run `E1.update()`, I get the error message `global name 'exp' is not defined`.

I've tried calling `from numpy import *` or also `import numpy as np` and changing the function call to `np.exp()` and I continue to get the error. Thinking that I had some sort of scoping problem or issues with namespace I've put this same import function at various locations, including in the `test.py` file, the top of the class file `WC_class.py`, even in the method:

```
class WC_unit:
    def __init__(self): [assign default pars from a dict including r, dt, tau, and Iapp]...
    def update(self):
        from numpy import *
        self.r += self.dt/self.tau * (-self.r + exp(self.Iapp))
```

I would really like to up my game and figure out how to write my own classes and use them with the awesome computing tools. I guess I'd like to know:

1. What am I doing wrong (probably a lot, I suspect). I think it's something with how I'm importing my class? but perhaps also scoping in the class itself.
2. Why does my class lose access to the numpy functions when I `import` it, but not when I run it like a script in the terminal?
3. I guess I also generally don't understand why people are so protective of their namespaces, i.e. why do so many code examples show `import numpy as np` and use all of the functions as `np.exp(x)`, etc. I don't have much of a computer science background so I could benefit a lot from any explanations you could provide- the documentation is kind of cryptic to me.

Python version: 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (x86_64)| (default, Aug 21 2014, 15:21:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)]
On Mac OSX 10.6.8

Comment: Stop doing `from numpy import *` and prefer `import numpy` and using `numpy.array`, `numpy.mean`, etc. This prevents namespace pollution which creates problems like you are seeing.

Comment: Please always show the *full traceback* for any error message in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `%run WC_class.py` in IPython, what you are doing is loading the contents of that source file directly into the interactive namespace. Because you've already called `from numpy import *` within your IPython session, `exp` is defined as `numpy.exp` within the set of globals for the current 'module' (which, in this case, is just the IPython interactive namespace), so when you call `exp()` in `WC_unit.update()` (or anywhere else within `WC_class.py`) it will work fine.

However, you do not do a `from numpy import *` at the top of `test.py`, therefore when you import `WC_unit` into your script `exp` has not been defined within the scope of the current module (which is now the `test` script).

You've tried `from numpy import *` within the `WC_unit.update()` method itself, but this will fail because [`import *` is only allowed at a module level](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13456481/1461210) (in fact you should have seen a `SyntaxWarning` about this when you tried to import `WC_unit`!). Since the import fails, `exp` is still undefined and the `WC_unit.update()` method will raise the `NameError` you're seeing.

What you *ought* to do is have a single import line at the top of any source file that uses numpy functions:

```
import numpy as np
```

then refer to any numpy functions via the `np.` namespace.

---

Regarding your third point, the main reason to do

```
import numpy as np

x = np.exp(y) # etc.
```

rather than

```
from numpy import *

x = exp(y)   # etc.
```

is that the latter method pollutes your global namespace.

Suppose you had already  defined your own function called `exp`. When you do `from numpy import *`, you will be overwriting your own function called `exp` with `numpy.exp`, so when you later call `exp(y)` it might not do what you expect it to. For example, this is exactly what happens to some of the built-in Python functions such as `sum` and `all`:

```
print(sum.__module__)
# __builtin__

from numpy import *

print(sum.__module__)
# numpy.core.fromnumeric
```

What's more, this is more-or-less irreversible - once you've done a `from module import *` there's no easy way to get rid of the stuff you've imported to your namespace (or restore any old modules or variables you've clobbered by importing over the top of them).

As long as you keep all of the contents of each module in its own separate namespace there is no risk of namespace collisions, and no ambiguity about where each function or class comes from. By convention we use `np` to refer to the namespace for numpy, `plt` for `matplotlib.pyplot` etc.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure if this is exactly what's going on, but I've definitely been able to learn a bit more about how classes and objects work, and break things down into smaller chunks. I'll probably be asking a few more philosophical-type questions as I learn how to write, I appreciate your thorough and straightforward answer. If anyone can link me to any tutorials about how to develop simulations using classes and such I would love to read them. in particular i'm having trouble figuring out how to structure my files... modules...